# List issue in python

Tags: python-3.x

Don't understand why it adds an empty list object to the end. Can someone explain and help me to write the proper code without this extra empty string?
Thank you!

```
mean_temp_list = mean_temp.readline().strip()
city_temp=mean_temp_list.split(",")
while mean_temp_list:
    mean_temp_list = mean_temp.readline().strip()
    city_temp+=mean_temp_list.split(",")
    print(city_temp)
['Beijing', 'China', '30.9', '-8.4', 'Cairo', 'Egypt', '34.7', '1.2']

['Beijing', 'China', '30.9', '-8.4', 'Cairo', 'Egypt', '34.7', '1.2', 'London', 'UK', '23.5', '2.1']

['Beijing', 'China', '30.9', '-8.4', 'Cairo', 'Egypt', '34.7', '1.2', 'London', 'UK', '23.5', '2.1', 'Nairobi', 'Kenya', '26.3', '10.5']

['Beijing', 'China', '30.9', '-8.4', 'Cairo', 'Egypt', '34.7', '1.2', 'London', 'UK', '23.5', '2.1', 'Nairobi', 'Kenya', '26.3', '10.5', 'New York City', 'USA', '28.9', '-2.8']

['Beijing', 'China', '30.9', '-8.4', 'Cairo', 'Egypt', '34.7', '1.2', 'London', 'UK', '23.5', '2.1', 'Nairobi', 'Kenya', '26.3', '10.5', 'New York City', 'USA', '28.9', '-2.8', 'Sydney', 'Australia', '26.5', '8.7']

['Beijing', 'China', '30.9', '-8.4', 'Cairo', 'Egypt', '34.7', '1.2', 'London', 'UK', '23.5', '2.1', 'Nairobi', 'Kenya', '26.3', '10.5', 'New York City', 'USA', '28.9', '-2.8', 'Sydney', 'Australia', '26.5', '8.7', 'Tokyo', 'Japan', '30.8', '0.9']

['Beijing', 'China', '30.9', '-8.4', 'Cairo', 'Egypt', '34.7', '1.2', 'London', 'UK', '23.5', '2.1', 'Nairobi', 'Kenya', '26.3', '10.5', 'New York City', 'USA', '28.9', '-2.8', 'Sydney', 'Australia', '26.5', '8.7', 'Tokyo', 'Japan', '30.8', '0.9', '']
```

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyYsH.png)

Comment: Please read how to provide a [mcve]. The **code must be in the question itself, not in a linked screenshot!**

Answer (score 0):

Because the string you are splitting has a trailing comma.

```
>>> 'a,b'.split(',')
['a', 'b']
>>> 'a,b,'.split(',')
['a', 'b', '']
#          ^
```

You should use `.strip(',')` to remove such trailing commas:

```
>>> 'a,b,'.strip(',').split(',')
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it didn't work out. And if it's so then why `while` triggers with the empty string? P.S. And sorry for mess with format of questions and topic. I'm new to this)

Comment: @OlegPlakida The `while` loop as nothing to do with it. 1. `split` creates a new list, and 2. `['']` still evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Finally! The problem was in the wrong order in `while` loop: at the last iteration `readline` was before writing the code, so it adds an empty string to the variable `city temp`. I swapped them and now it works properly. Your answer gave me a clue. Thank you!